# Colored source in java project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, colors, syntax-highlighting

when I create a New Project in Eclipse, source files such as .html .xml are colored, but when I create New Java Project they aren't.
How can I change this ?
Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to right-click on the .xml (or similar) file, choose "Open with" and select the right editor. If the editor is not listed in the menu, choose a new one with "Other..." option.

Answer (score 0):

On the files that are missing the color coding right-click in either the project or package explorer with the mouse and check the `open with` entry on the context menu.  It will show which editor is active for the file.  I'm guessing it's the text editor - just select the correct editor for the file (for example, the XML editor) and you should see the coloring.

Answer (score 0):

For mixed HTML and Java projects, I use Dynamic Web Project. You might have to download WTP if you do not use the Eclipse Java EE edition.